# UITableview Delegate method calls before json method

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

In my project I use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kLatestKivaLoansURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

});
```

written in `viewDidLoad`. Then I have implemented `fetchedData:`.

Problem is that I have used `UITableView` to display the array data from the JSON a nd before `fetchedData:` is called the tableview's `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called.

I write there `[myarray count];` so it returns 0, because it calls before fetchdata.   Any

Solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `reloadData` on the table view after you have stored the updated data. It's fine that the table view loads before then (though you may want to add a progress indicator to let the user know what's happening).

Comment: Thanks man.it works .but is there any way call fetchdata method before numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Only to call it before the table view controller is displayed. What you have now is fine, you just need to decide how to keep the user informed.